# How to install Chart.js in Laravel? ("Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined")

Tags: laravel, npm, chart.js, laravel-mix

I don't know, how much time I lost looking for solution for this issue. I wanted to use Chart.js in my Laravel project, so I followed instructions described [here](https://github.com/fxcosta/laravel-chartjs).

1. `composer require fx3costa/laravelchartjs` (runned)
2. `Fx3costa\LaravelChartJs\Providers\ChartjsServiceProvider::class` (added in the right place)
3. `npm i chart.js` (used to install chart.js)
4. In my controller and blade I used code from example 1 (Line Chart / Radar Chart)

After that the error appeared: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined`. Before and after that I was trying different solutions, but always something was wrong and I think this one should work for me. I probably missed something obvious, but very important.

Have you any ideas?
Should I add something to `webpack.mix.js` or `bootstrap.js` files after installing with `npm`?

EDIT:

If I put `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>` in my `head` section of blade, everything is working fine, but I'm using `laravel-mix` to use a locale file instead of link.

Comment: In the bootstrap.js you should add this line: `window.chart = require('chart.js');`

Comment: @work service Yeah, I tried it before, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chart.js` must be loaded **before** content in order to use it in any `Controller`. I was loading my `laravel-mix` variables **after** HTML content (because it includes some big libralies like jQuery etc.), so that's why it couldn't work.

**SOLUTION:**

At the end of my document I still have my previous script

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
```

But now I made a new `loadBefore.js` file in `resources/js` directory with one line of code:

```
require('chart.js/dist/chart.js');
```

If there will be any reason to put there any other javascript code, it will be easy to put it there.

I also added this file to `webpack.mix.js` like this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/loadBefore.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps();
```

And of course at the end I added this script to the head section in my blade:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/loadBefore.js') }}"></script>
```

Now everything is working and I'm using already existing in my Laravel files `chart.js` file. I don't know, someone knows an easier solution, so for now I'm accepting my answer, but I'm still open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

why you just dont copy the content of

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>
```

in a file at your local, for example: /public/js/chart.js
and load it in head

```
<script src="{{asset('js/chart.js')}}"></script>
```