# Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined in Laravel mix

Tags: javascript, chart.js, laravel-mix

I used chart.js in Laravel mix in my boostrap.js

```
 import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

in my blade tamplete

```
var myChart = window.chart(
        $('#chart'),
        config,
    );
```

but always get Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it just there

[How to install Chart.js in Laravel? ("Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68376221/how-to-install-chart-js-in-laravel-uncaught-referenceerror-chart-is-not-defi)

its very simply we need to declare the Chert in file in a new js file.

create resource/js/loadbefore.js

```
require('chart.js/dist/chart.js');
```

in our webpack.mix.js

```
.js('resources/js/loadbefore.js', 'public/js')
```

execute `npm run dev`

after that in our blade tamplete we call loadbefore.js in the head part, an we can use Chart whitout any promblem